# InMobi Reward Ads via AdMob Mediation cannot show

Tags: android, admob, inmobi, mobile-ad-mediation

I got a trouble about showing reward(video) ads via AdMob mediation.

All I did is the following.

(1) Add the library of InMobi

InMobi-6.0.4.jar

libadapterinmobi.jar

(2) Add the following Code in MainActivity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (globals.adFlag == 1) {
        // 2017.01.16 Add by Kazuhiko
        // Show the Video Ads
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Preload the next video ad.
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
            {
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        loadRewardedVideoAd();
        mRewardedVideoAd.show();
        this.setVisible(true);
        globals.adFlag = 0;
    }

}

private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
    AdRequest adRewardRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .build();
    mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(globals.ADMOB_VDO, adRewardRequest );
}
```

(3) Add the following line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <activity
        android:name="com.inmobi.rendering.InMobiAdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|smallestScreenSize|screenSize"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <meta-data
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
         android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

(4) Add thefollowing line in app.gradle

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
```

My app can show Google ads. But mediation is something wrong.
What is the problem?
Please let me know how can I fix it.

Comment: Did you get some clue? i am also trying to do the same